# Can you insert the text from a textbox in a report to a table in MS Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using this code in a form and it works but it's not working in a report:

```
Private Sub AddCustomerSoldTo_Click()
  CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Customer(Company, [Customer Sold To]) " & _
      " VALUES('" & Me.Company & "','" & Me.Add_CustomerSoldTo & "')"
End Sub
```

I want to run the report and have the user to be able to add a customer to a table if they do not see it in the report. I am currently using Access 2016. Thanks!

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Is it giving you an error message (and if so, what is it)? Is it inserting the wrong data? Is it causing the report to hang?

Comment: Sorry. It will not add Me.Add_CustomerSoldTo. It leaves a null value in my table but it will add Me.Company which is also a textbox. The only difference is that Me.Company has a control source (it was generated in the report from a query) Me.Add_CustomerSoldTo was a textbox I added to the report. But no error message is generated.

Comment: First determine that the procedure is trying to send the company name. Add these two lines so that they are the first 2 lines:  `Dim companyName As String        companyName = Me.Company`.  Then set a debug breakpoint, run the code and see if companyName has a value.